# js countdown doesn't show time in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a countdown using js,This code is supposed to show a seconds,minutes, hours countdown between 2 dates on an HTML page.
Everything is working well in desktop
but I have a problem in mobile he doesn't show the time but a problem  [image: like this]
I don't have any idea why!! there is any problem in js code or css .. ?
any help please !

```js
 // Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jun 26, 2020 9:00:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML =  hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
  }, 1000);
```

```css
  
  .gauge {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    transition: height .3s ease;
}

.progress {
    height: 48px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 48px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    transition: background .6s ease;
}
.progress .progress__labels {
    color: #fff;
}
.progress__labels--spaced {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.progress__labels {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.progress__labels * {
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.progress__labels--spaced .progress__label--right {
    margin-left: auto;
}
.progress__determinate {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: width .2s linear;
}
.bg--warning {
    background-image: #EB0F9B;
}
.bg--warning {
    background-color: #EB0F9B!important;
}
.gauge__countdown, .gauge__percentage {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.carousel--desktop, .hidden {
    display: none!important;
}

*, :after, :before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media (min-width: 992px){

.progress {
    height: 72px;
    line-height: 72px;
}
.gauge__countdown, .gauge__percentage {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}
.gauge__countdown, .gauge__percentage {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){  
.m-visible-inline {
    display: inline!important;
}

.title2, h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.gauge__percentage {
    margin: 0 6px;
}



.m-visible-inline {
    display: inline!important;
}

.gauge__percentage {
    margin: 0 6px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="gauge"><div class="progress-container progress-container--medium"><div class="progress progress--normal"><div id="prog" class="progress__determinate bg--warning" style="width: 20%;"></div><div class="progress__labels progress__labels--spaced"><span class="progress__label progress__label--left"><span><span class="title2 hidden m-visible-inline">Plus que</span><span class="gauge__percentage">31%</span><span class="title2 hidden m-visible-inline">Le stock est pillé!</span></span></span><span class="progress__label progress__label--right"><span id="countdown" class="countdown gauge__countdown"> </span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Could you add some OS and browser/browser version info please?

Comment: Chrome in iPhone 6

Comment: iPhone 6, so probably iOS 12, but which Chrome version?

Comment: Version 83.0.4103.88 but the problem also in other devices

Comment: *All* other devices?

Comment: yes but in desktop work well 
I didn't test in an iPad ..

Answer (score 0):

I've a simple JS countdown -

```
// I set the time_remaining during page load

let time remaining = $("#time-remaining).val(); 
let countdown = setInterval(function () {
    let minutes = Math.floor(time_remaining / 60);
    let seconds = time_remaining % 60;
    // Code to displaying minutes and seconds in html
    // goes here.
    if(time_remaining === 0) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
    }
    
}, 1000);
```

Now, in order to compensate for the halted setInterval, I make use of the visibility change event as follows -

```
$(document).on('visibilitychange', function() {
 if(document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    axios.get('/get-time-remaining')
         .then(function (response) {
            time_remaining = response.data.time_remaining
    });
 }
});
```

That is, whenever the user screen gets visible, I fetch the time remaining from server and update my time_remaining variable.

This approach works okay; does introduce a bit of delay but does the job.

However, I've observed that visibilitychange triggers ONLY WHEN user's mobile screen has screen-lock enabled.

If the user unlocks the mobile; visibilitychange event is triggered and I get my time_remaining as expected.

However, without a screen-lock, that even is not triggered; and thus, the countdown does not function properly.

I've considered different approaches such as -

Polling the server every few seconds and fetch the correct time remaining; and adjust the countdown on user's mobile.

Making use of service worker; but I'm not exactly sure how to make it work.

Maybe there's some other JS event that gets triggered when the user has the browser window 'focused' or 'visible'; on which I can trigger my AJAX call to the server to get correct time remaining.